# how to create two Async functions which after waiting for 10 sec returns sum of any number of arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, async-await

How to Create two async functions, where first function will wait for 10 sec and returns sum of any numbers of argument of type number(using the spread operator) and another will wait for the first function to finish and add 10 more to the return value of first function and finally returns the output.
I'm thankful for any help as these are pretty new for me....
I have tried this ...

```
var a=0;
setTimeout(function() { Addition(); }, 10000);
async function Addition() 
{
  for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  a += arguments[i];    
}
return a;
}
async function secondFunction()
{
 await Addition();
 a = a + 10;
 return a;
};
 console.log(Addition(2, 3));
```

Comment: you never call `secondFunction`

Comment: Here's a two second version: https://jsfiddle.net/toy893ha/

Comment: @ChrisG yeah..... solved..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the combination of returning a resolved Promise and setTimeout. In the first async function you're awaiting the Promise to be resolved, and that will only happen after the setTimeout function runs for 10 seconds and then it would return the `resolve` argument.

```
async function first(...numbers) {
  const result = numbers.reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
  return result;
}

function second(n1) {
  return n1 + 10;
}

(async () => {
  const result1 = await first(10, 10, 10, 10);
  const result2 = second(result1);
  console.log(result2); // results in 50
})();
```

Comment: @qasimalbaqali......thanking you for the edit, but here, if i want to pass n number of arguments, please tell me exactly where should I be using the for loop and the spread operator?

Comment: @Gloang At which step would you want to add the `n` number of arguments, is it in the first function?

Comment: @qasimalbaqali- yes in the first function, Should I be using for loop or reduce() ...any other way?

Comment: @Gloang I modified the answer for using the spread operators. And yes, you would use the reduce method to achieve a much more cleaner way.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to use asynchronous functions apart from the setTimeout which we use for the timing.

You can just pass the return value of the first function into the second function

```js
let numberArray = [[10, 5, 25], [-3, 4, 7], [30, 30, 30]];

setTimeout(() => {
  numberArray.forEach(array => secondFunction(Addition(...array)));
}, 10000);

function Addition() {
  let a = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    a += arguments[i];
  }

  return a;
}

function secondFunction(a) {
  a += 10;
  return a;
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .....But what if i have to use spread operator ....?.

Comment: I just edited the answer you can see the way I did it now